# Singular points of space curves and geometric genus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Some time ago, I asked what is the contribution of a singularity with
multiplicity greater than $2$ to the geometric genus of a space curve.
For plane curves, there is a simple formula, provided that the tangent
vectors are distinct. For space curves, I ended up with a conjecture that generalises this formula. For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that the curve is a complete intersection and the defining polynomials $P_k$ have same degree.
Let us denote by $d_k$ the highest integer such that all the derivatives
of $P_k$ of order smaller that $d_k$ are equal to zero at some point $O$. For
convenience, I call this number $\cal multiplicity$ of $P_k$.
If
some polynomials have same multiplicity, a linear combination of them might
give a polynomial with higher multiplicity. Let us choose a combination
of polynomials such that this does not occur. Then, the singularity $O$
reduces the genus by an amount equal to 
$$
\frac{\prod_k d_k}{2}\sum_k (d_k-1),
$$
provided that the tangent vectors are distinct. This formula reduces to the one for plane curve. I have an intuitive argument for the formula, but not a proof. Is it correct and known? If it is correct, what is the proof? I tried many examples, and I never found a disproof.

Comment: It is not known, because it is false. Take the intersection of two 
surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ which are smooth at $O$, with the same tangent space. Then $d_1=d_2=1$, your formula gives $0$, but the curve is singulat at $O$.

Comment: Your example does not satisfy the condition that a combination of the two polynomials does not give another polynomial with higher multiplicity.

Comment: Anyway, this is already false for plane curves — double points may reduce the genus as much as you want.

Comment: Concerning your remark, could it be possible to have an example of plane curve with such property?

Comment: $Y^2Z^{2n-1}=X^{2n+1}$. At $(0,0,1)$, the genus reduces by $n$.

Comment: It seems that you didn't read carefully my question. First, the tangent vectors of the curve at the singularity (0,0,1) are not distinct. Second, there is another singularity at (0,1,0) with high multiplicity. Each one contributes to the reduction of the genus. What I am considering is a curve with m singularities, each one satisfying the mentioned property of distinct tangent vectors. My claim is that each singularity contributes to reduce the genus according to the formula above.